# Configuring database alarms for and AWS RDS datbase

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, rds, laravel

I'm using an AWS RDS MySQL 8.0db.t3.micro 100GB DB for an app and am trying to determine the best alarms to set (the Laravel application is served through Vapor and through their UI, you can receive notifications if there are database spikes).  Is there common practice for what's consider spikes in the maximum number of connections, average number of connections, and average CPU utilizaion?

Comment: Please review this URL - https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/  -  
There is no mention of using this instance type for production systems.  Your customary workload should guide you to spike level settings.  Consider setting alarm levels when current load * 1.25 usage is exceeded should make you aware of unexpected activities.

Comment: I'm using Laravel Vapor and this is one of the options.  I also see it here (https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/pricing/?pg=pr&loc=2&refid=90549db2-2f76-4808-b8ca-3e23b6ae3f04). Is the ec2 instance type different from the RDS options?

Comment: That would be a question for Amazon.